# KL Divergence and Maximum Likelihood Estimate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, optimization, maximum-likelihood

We can show that minimizing $KL(p_{\theta^*}||p_\theta)$ w.r.t $\theta$ is equivalent to MLE of $\theta$ where $\theta^*$ is the true parameter. I am wondering what does minimizing $KL(p_{\theta}||p_{\theta^*})$ w.r.t $\theta$ result in? Is there a known estimator that does this? Examples showcasing the difference are most welcome.

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to MLE of $\theta*$ where $\theta$ is the true parameter?

Comment: @DaviBarreira Thanks for the Observation. I have edited the post to clarify. In the second case, again $\theta^*$ is a constant and the variable is $\theta$.